# browser error while declaring CSS3 variables, Expected RBRACE, This rule looks for recoverable syntax error

Tags: html, css, csslint

I am trying to use variables in my CSS3 file, I have used following code

```
:root{
--nvc-theme: green;
--nvc-themelite: grey;
}
```

this is the css I am using to declare two variables in my project but when I compile CSS with csslint it is showing error

```
ERROR: Expected RBRACE at line 17, col 3. This rule looks for recoverable syntax 
errors. (errors) Browsers: All
```

and it is also showing

```
WARNING: Rule is empty. Rules without any properties specified should be removed.
 (empty-rules) Browsers: All
```

I know this warning because in  the root element I have used only variables I didn't declare any css properties just variables so it is showing a warning, but how can I overcome this situation. Any solution helps a lot. Thank you

Comment: Acording to this lib (https://www.npmjs.com/package/csslint-next), CSS variables seems to be not supported by csslint. Maybe give a try to this one or another one?

Comment: thanks. but i have already read that some thing issue with csslint only but i have a limitation to use csslint only

Comment: I don't know it very much, maybe you can set some exception or disable some rules to prevent these errors? Since it's a parsing problem, it feels like you won't be able to fix it easily though... it seems rather low level.

Comment: How to set an exception or disable rules

Comment: I don't know if it's possible, you should check the docs, but using eslint, that's how it works!

Answer (score 1):

Given an outstanding [issue on github](https://github.com/CSSLint/csslint/issues/720) for this problem, and another issue asking ["Is anyone here?"](https://github.com/CSSLint/csslint/issues/719) with no response from the devs and no real way to merge fix in, it doesn't seem this will be fixed any time soon.

So your only real option is to migrate to a different lint such as [stylelint](https://stylelint.io/)

Comment: for one single issue changing the whole project lint? is that a good idea? and i have posted issue in github also before posting this question

Comment: @AravindReddy its not the issue, its whether the project is no longer maintained - as it is beginning to appear to be. Anyway, the answer (today at least) is that there is no way to fix it, and one solution is to change linter to one that does.